# Looking to be able to do substitutions in JSON file using jq

Tags: jq, template

I am looking to design a JQ function which would allow for management of substitution of data from within the JSON file itself along with shell environment substitutions (and shell function invocations).  For example I have this file...

```json
{
    "services" : {
        "blah" : {
            "server" : "https://my.server.home",
            "role_id" : "ABC",
            "login" : {
                "path" : "v1/auth/approle/login",
                "connection_data" : {
                    "role_id" : "{{services.blah.role_id}}",
                    "secret_id" : "${BLAH_SECRET}.${MY_DEFINED_ENVVAR}"
                },
                "other" : "$( get_workspace )/ght"
            }
        }
    },
    "applications" : {
        "curl" : {
            "version" : "7.80"
        }
    }
}
```

and would like this result:

```json
{
  "services": {
    "blah": {
      "server": "my.server.home",
      "role_id": "ABC",
      "login": {
        "path": "v1/auth/approle/login",
        "connection_data": {
          "role_id": "ABC",
          "secret_id": "my-secret.xyz"
        },
        "other": "/abc/my_workspace/ght"
      }
    }
  },
  "applications": {
    "curl": {
      "version": "7.80"
    }
  }
}
```

In doing, so I want to be able to control the markers used to delineate intra-access to the JSON file for substitution from those use to show that a shell function should be run versus shell environment variables.

I presume the proper way would be use jq's **walk** method in conjunction with a suitable function that tests for **string** to allow for processing the line multiple times until it does not change (i.e. all substitutions have been completed).

Any suggestions???

Comment: You showed us example input. Now [show us](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) the corresponding output you're looking for.

Comment: {
 "services" : {
  "blah" : {
   "server" : "https://my.server.home",
   "role_id" : "ABC",
   "login" : {
    "path" : "v1/auth/approle/login",
    "connection_data" : {
     "role_id" : "ABC",
     "secret_id" : "my-secret.xyz"
    },
    "other" : "/abc/my_workspace/ght"
   }
  }
 },
 "applications" : {
  "curl" : {
   "version" : "7.80"
  }
 }
}

Comment: @MichaelKlusmanIII whenever you're asked to provide an information from a question in a comment, you are supposed to add back the information in the question, not give this information in a comment. I added it for you, but please remember this for an other time. Also, you should take the tour: https://unix.stackexchange.com/tour

Comment: It appears that you just want [mustache](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mustache_(template_system)) or similar templating engine. If there's something constraining the solution to use `jq`, the original question does not spell that out.

Comment: The input seems to have two entierly different syntaxes for data placeholders. The non-`{{}}` bit(s) could be handled by expansions in a here-document in the shell.  The `{{}}`-bit(s) might need a templating engine, as a previous commentator mentioned.